# How to format training/testing sets for Deep Belief neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to use implement the code from [this page](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/DBN.py). But I can't work out how to format the data (training set / testing set) correctly. My code:

```
    numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)
    dbn = DBN(numpy_rng=numpy_rng, n_ins=2,hidden_layers_sizes=[50, 50, 50],n_outs=1)

    train_set_x = [
        ([1,2],[2,]), #first element in the tuple is the input, the second is the output
        ([4,5],[5,])
    ]

    testing_set_x = [
        ([6,1],[3,]), #same format as the training set
    ]

    #when I looked at the load_data function found elsewhere in the tutorial (I'll show the code they used at the bottom for ease) I found it rather confusing, but this was my first attempt at recreating what they did
    train_set_xPrime = [theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][0],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True),theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][1],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)]

    pretraining_fns = dbn.pretraining_functions(train_set_x=train_set_xPrime,batch_size=10,k=1)
```

which produced this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/spudzee1111/Desktop/Code/NNChatbot/DeepBeliefScratch.command", line 837, in <module>
        pretraining_fns = dbn.pretraining_functions(train_set_x=train_set_xPrime,batch_size=10,k=1)
      File "/Users/spudzee1111/Desktop/Code/NNChatbot/DeepBeliefScratch.command", line 532, in pretraining_functions
        n_batches = train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[0] / batch_size
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_value'
```

I can't work out how the input is supposed to be formatted. I tried using theano.shared on the list, so that it would be:

```
    train_set_xPrime = theano.shared([theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][0],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True),theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][1],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)],borrow=True)
```

but then it said:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/spudzee1111/Desktop/Code/NNChatbot/DeepBeliefScratch.command", line 834, in <module>
        train_set_xPrime = theano.shared([theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][0],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True),theano.shared(numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][1],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True)],borrow=True) #,borrow=True),numpy.asarray(train_set_x[0][1],dtype=theano.config.floatX),borrow=True))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/compile/sharedvalue.py", line 228, in shared
        (value, kwargs))
    TypeError: No suitable SharedVariable constructor could be found. Are you sure all kwargs are supported? We do not support the parameter dtype or type. value="[<TensorType(float64, vector)>, <TensorType(float64, vector)>]". parameters="{'borrow': True}"
```

I tried other combinations but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(123)
dbn = DBN(numpy_rng=numpy_rng, n_ins=2, hidden_layers_sizes=[50, 50, 50], n_outs=1)

train_set = [
    ([1,2],[2,]),
    ([4,5],[5,])
]

train_set_x = [train_set[i][0] for i in range(len(train_set))]
nparray = numpy.asarray(train_set_x, dtype=theano.config.floatX)
train_set_x = theano.shared(nparray, borrow=True)

pretraining_fns = dbn.pretraining_functions(train_set_x=train_set_x, batch_size=10, k=1)
```

The method `pretraining_fns` is expecting as an input a shared variable of size (number of samples, dimension of inputs). You could check this by looking at the shape of the MNIST dataset, the standard input for this example

It doesn't take a list as an input because this method is only for the pre-training functions. DBNs are pre-trained with an unsupervised learning algorithm, so it doesn't make sense to use the labels

Furthermore, the input list to make your numpy array doesn't make sense. `train_set_x[0][0]` yields only the first training example. You want `train_set_xPrime` to have all training examples. Even if you did `train_set_x[0]` you would have the first training example but with the labels